# Edit pending disable the review edit button

Tags: bug, review-queues

At my rep level I don't have the right to validate a pending edit.

If the question has an edit pending, clicking the edit button in review won't do anything.

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19768483#
On browser: Internet Explorer / Edge / Chrome 
Error: No error in console 
Repro: 100% with my account no matter the pc.

Not test with an other account. 
Not tested outside of my LAN. 
Cache Cleaned. Browser fresh instal on a vm. 
Edit "work"(red popup pending edit is displayed) directly on the question.

Can any low rep user confirm before the ends on the pending edit?

Comment: Unrelated: thanks for being the one person today who started his feedback with "I appreciate your efforts" (my wording here).